# Heroku - how to flush Rails logs after each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I'm running a Rails 3 app on Heroku.

This is the output of `heroku logs --tail --source app`:
https://gist.github.com/4000998

The `Started GET "/"` lines appear in real time as HTTP requests are made.  However, the `Processing by Controller` lines get buffered and then dumped to the log all at once.

This makes it very hard to debug issues in the app as it is difficult to match up the controller logs with the rest of the app's logs.  How do I get the buffered logs to flush after each request?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your `config.ru`:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've identified the root of the problem in rails_log_stdout though, a plugin that Heroku injects when the slug is compiled.  See [here](https://github.com/heroku/rails_log_stdout/pull/1).

Comment: This worked for me:
`gem 'rails_log_stdout', :git => 'https://github.com/mattjbray/rails_log_stdout'`